# How to trigger Quartz.NET job multiple times per second

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I'm currently using cron triggers to trigger job. The smallest granularity is 1 second, so it seems that I can at most trigger this job once every second.

Is it possible to trigger the job more often than once every second? If so, how would I go about it?

Multiple schedules for the job, each with an every-second-trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to SimpleTrigger which allows you to configure interval in milliseconds. Cron trigger isn't ideal for such scheduling, it has more overhead than needed when you want to go sub-second.